# setting the child opacity bigger from it's parent

Tags: html, css

so here is my code , obviously it doesn't work  .... basically i want to be able to see `#child` while parent is hidden

```
 <style>
 #parent { opacity : 0 }
 #parent:hover { opacity : 1 }
 #child { opacity:1 }
 </style>

  <div id="parent">
       <h1 id="child"> title </h1>
       <span>aaaa</span>
       <span>aaaa</span>
       <span>aaaa</span>
    </div>
```

it's part of very big code with lot's of jquery effects and codes which someone else has wrote and i don't want to mess anything so i really don't want to move #child outside of #parent

Comment: I'm pretty sure the opacities multiply eg stack. Child inherits parent's opacity stack.

Comment: You mean [this](http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/qase4n5z/)?

Comment: @chipChocolate.py close ... i want child to be visible so something like this http://jsfiddle.net/qase4n5z/1/ but hover in this code doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

An element's opacity is derived from its parent:

> [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity): an element and its contained children all have the same opacity
>   relative to the element's background, even if the element and its
>   children have different opacities relative to one another.

One way to get around this is to use rgba colors instead of opacity:

```css
 #parent {
     color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
 }
 #parent:hover {
     color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
 }
 #child {
     color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
 }
```

```html
<div id="parent">
 <h1 id="child"> title </h1>
 <span>aaaa</span>
 <span>aaaa</span>
 <span>aaaa</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks will test it , but i thought color was for changing font/text color

Comment: Text is all you have in your example.

Comment: i see , so it wont hide the background and other stuff ? like if parent has a red background